# grub-common.service - Record successful boot for GRUB Loaded: error (Reason: Exec format error)

Tags: server, grub2

The server was had a pending reboot, and after reboot I'm getting some errors when installing any package.

```
Failed to start grub-common.service: Unit grub-common.service is not loaded properly: Exec format error.
See system logs and 'systemctl status grub-common.service' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript grub-common, action "start" failed.
● grub-common.service - Record successful boot for GRUB
   Loaded: error (Reason: Exec format error)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Looking for any information on what steps to try to troubleshoot this.

Thanks

Comment: What did you do from the time it wanted a reboot till you actually did it?

Comment: Nothing but the reboot.  When I saw a reboot was pending when logging into the box I figured it best to complete that before doing anything on the box.